# homology of the union of two circles and a sphere tangent in a point to the two circles

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Came across this question in an old qual: Compute the homology of the union of two circles and a sphere tangent in a point to the two circles.

Having a hard time visualizing the figure. Is it the figure eight curve with a sphere attached to it or something else? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That's what I would say.

Comment: So is it like $S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^2$ ?

Comment: The way it is written it is more like $S^1\vee S^2\vee S^1 $. But the homology is the same.

Comment: Just use corollary 2.25 in Hatcher. The homology of the wedge sum is the direct sum of the homologies.

Comment: This is why pictures should be used to describe a space...